# Crop and recreate UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, crop

I want to crop a UIImage (not imageview), before doing pixel operations on it. Is there a reliable way to do this in ios framework?

Here are the related methods in android I am using:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int, int, android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29)

Comment: maybe [this is help-full](https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ios+crop+image&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=g_ZHU8GBC-ag8wf98IDoAw)

Comment: (not imageview).. most of those are cropping for imageview, i do not have a use for that method.

Comment: and? there are so many articles about UIImage (note: no view present). of CGImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
-(UIImage *)cropCanvas:(UImage *)input x1:(int)x1 y1:(int)y1 x2:(int)x2 y2:(int)y2{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x1, y1, input.size.width-x2-x1, input.size.height-y2-y1);
    CGImageRef imageref = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([input CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageref];
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
-(UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size image:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    // Draw the scaled image in the current context
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];

    // Create a new image from current context
    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Pop the current context from the stack
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Return our new scaled image
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look at:

- The [`CoreAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html) Apple framework to create an image context, draw in it and save this as a UIImage in RAM or save it to disk.
- The [`CoreImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) Apple framework if you want a powerful and fully customizable image manipulation solution.
- A third party lib to crop and resize images: CocoaPods is a great way to quickly integrate that kind of libs… Here is a list of a some interesting [image manipulation pods](http://cocoapods.org/?q=image%20crop).